# Is it possible to open gallery of an android device using html5

Tags: android, html

I tried for the following:

```
<input type = "file" accept = "image/*"> </input>
```

It gives option to select one of Camera or Gallery. Is there any way so that Gallery can be launched directly?

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Package.name.of.Gallery");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

The package name is usually something like this : `com.android.gallery3d`

Comment: I think its for Java. I need a way which works in html5

Comment: You tagged Android. 
What does your app exactly use? And which software are you using to build it?

Comment: I am making a webpage using html5 which should have an option to browse gallery of an android device

Comment: Technically, when your webpage would require someone to go to the gallery, the web browser will be able to access the android's device gallery.

You are building a web page; Not a web browser.